# Disable global search in GTK file chooser

Tags: gnome, configuration, gtk, mate, ubuntu-mate

As of Ubuntu Mate 19.04, the "Open File" dialog (`GtkFileChooserDialog`) will search through the whole file system instead of just the current folder whenever I start typing. How can I revert this to the old behavior?

Comment: Start by typing `./` (for files in the current directory) or press CTRL+L.